# Why interval property fails for this types of problems: $|y-a|>b, a,b\in\mathbb{R}?$

Tags: inequality, absolute-value, interval-arithmetic

**The interval property reads:** Given $b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $b>0$, we have $|x|<b$ if and only if $-b\lt x \lt b$. **Corollary reads:** Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $b\gt 0$ be given. For all $y\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $|y-a|<b$ if and only if $a-b < y < a+b$.

This clearly works when an equation is something like $|x+2|<1$, but fails when $|x+2|>1$. Why?

i.e. the **false** solution is $-2-1>x>-2+1\iff-3>x>-1$. This clearly fails as $-3\not\gt-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because by definition of an absolute value we have: $$|y-a|>b$$ it's
$$y-a>b$$ or
$$y-a<-b$$
For example $$|y+2|>1$$ it's
$$y+2>1$$ or $$y+2<-1,$$ which gives
$$(-\infty,-3)\cup(-1,+\infty).$$
Also, $$|y+2|>-1$$ it's $\mathbb R$, which we can get by the previous way:
$$y+2>-1$$ or
$$y+2<1,$$ which is
$$(-3,+\infty)\cup(-\infty,-1),$$ which is $\mathbb R.$

Comment: I think I got the point, but I think you made a mistake: $|y+2|>-1 \neq  |y+2|<1$. Because $|y+2|>1 \cup  |y+2|<1 = \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @u1731182 I think you want to solve $|y+2|>-1,$ which gives $\mathbb R$. The inequality $|y+2|<1$ gives $-1<y+2<1$ or $-3<y<-1.$ See please better your question. Also, see please better my post.